# Create an iPhone app which redirects user to a mobile/HTML5 website

Tags: iphone, html, redirect, mobile-website

Is it possible to create an iPhone app which just redirects the user to my HTML5 mobile website? If it is possible, do you know if Apple can refuse my app? (Maybe it is written somewhere in their Terms & Conditions?)

The aim is to be present on the App Store, but to only have one version of my website to maintain.

Comment: Pretty sure this is off-topic for SO... I'm also pretty sure that Apple would reject that app.

Comment: apple will reject a native app that doesn't have enough functionality to differentiate itself from a web app so if all you do is redirect then it will be rejected.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have a web app, you should make an iOS app that is nothing more than a `UIWebView` that points to your URL. A lot of apps do this, and in most instances, you really wouldn't know it's not native unless you are a developer. For example, the Discover card app uses this technique. The only caveat is it should be a **web *app*** and not just a **web *site***, i.e. it should do something useful and look like a native app instead of just being a web page with general information. Otherwise, you will be subject to this:

> **2.12** Apps that are not very useful, are simply web sites bundled as apps, or do not provide any lasting entertainment value may be
>   rejected

Comment: We've iOS app beta version developed which is redirecting me to browser and opening with url while opening the app. How can we stop opening it in browser and open in app itself?. We're new to iOS apps. Helps are much appreciated

Answer (score 3):

Yes you **CAN** create such an application. **However**, apple **WILL** reject such an application because of their [Guidelines](http://developer.apple.com/appstore/resources/approval/guidelines.html).

```
2.12 Apps that are not very useful, are simply web sites bundled as apps, or do not provide any lasting entertainment value may be rejected
```

The key to this would be *Not very useful*, since all it does is open a web browser and direct to your site.